# How to make a onClick handler for a functonal component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick, react-component

**The goal is to make the App component do something(execute activateLasers in this case) when clicked**

**console gives me this:**

> src\index.js
> Line 8:12:  'activateLasers' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function App() {

  function activateLasers(){
    console.log('Lasers activated!');
  };

  return (
   <div>
     <h1>some text</h1>
   </div>
  )
}
  // ========================================
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <App onClick='{activateLasers}' />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: `<App onClick={activateLasers} />` https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for me.Where do I put the activateLasers function?

Comment: You're asking why you're getting downvoted: the reason is that stackoverflow is not a tutorial site for newbies but intended as a last resort, after exhaustive debugging and research have failed. Your issue is caused by not knowing the fundamentals of JS and React, and questions like that usually receive downvotes. That's just how things work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have defined the function `activateLasers` inside the `App` function and it's unavailable outside its [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div onClick={props.onClick}>
      <h1>some text</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

function activateLasers(){
    console.log('Lasers activated!')
}
  
ReactDOM.render(
    <App onClick={activateLasers} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Also, pay attention that expressions in JSX should not be inserted inside quotation marks.

And about the error you said, it's simply because that function isn't used inside its parent scope.

**UPDATE:** If you want to use that function inside the component itself, simply use it inside it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function App() {
  function activateLasers(){
    console.log('Lasers activated!')
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={activateLasers}>
      <h1>some text</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I corrected my mystakes and I get no errors but the functiont doesnt seem to execute when I click.
P.S. Also Im realy new to stackoverflow and programming in general, is something wrong with my question cause I am getting disliked to hell here!

Comment: @Kovil I updated my answer. It's ok, It's the beginning of your journey and you'll learn as we all did. Just make sure you've searched enough before asking questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `activateLasers` function is "never used" because it is outside the component scope.

A way to apply the function in the correct scope would be:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function App() {

  function activateLasers(){
    console.log('Lasers activated!');
  };

  return (
   <div onClick='{activateLasers}'>
     <h1>some text</h1>
   </div>
  )
}
  // ========================================
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```